# How to make this diagram in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-graphdrawing

I have never used latex for drawing before. Could anyone help to draw the following, please:

[image]

Comment: I've never drawn graphs before, so to help you I would have to read the manual and figure it out, which is precisely what you should be doing.  You might search here for examples.

Comment: First one should be quite easy, the second one you can work with tikz-3d to have an easy placement of the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, in the future, post the code you have tried to write and explain what specific problem you are struggling with.
That being said, here is a (verbose) solution using plain TikZ.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \tikzset{%
            end node/.style = {%
                draw,
                minimum size     = 5pt,
                inner sep        = 0pt,
                fill             = black,
            },
            star end/.style = {%
                star,
                end node,
                star point ratio = 2.25,
            },
            diamond end/.style = {%
                diamond,
                end node,
            },
            circle end/.style = {%
                circle,
                end node,
            },
            triangle end/.style = {%
                regular polygon,
                regular polygon sides = 3,
                shape border rotate = 180,
                end node,
            },
        }
    
        \draw (0, 0) coordinate (A)
            -- ++(0, 2) coordinate (B)
                node[midway, left] {$1$}
            -- ++(2, 0) coordinate (C)
            -- ++(0, -2) coordinate (D)
            -- cycle
                node[midway, above] {$1$};
        
        \node[below] at (A) {$00$};
        \node[diamond end] at (A) {};
        \node[above] at (B) {$10$};
        \node[star end] at (B) {};
        \node[above] at (C) {$11$};
        \node[diamond end] at (C) {};
        \node[below] at (D) {$01$};
        \node[star end] at (D) {};
    
        \draw (4, 0, 1) coordinate (E) 
                -- ++(0, 2, 0) coordinate (F)
                    node[midway, left] {$1$}
                -- ++(2, 0, 0) coordinate (G)
                -- ++(0, -2, 0) coordinate (H)
                -- cycle
                    node[midway, above] {$1$};
        \draw (F) -- (G)
                -- ++(0, 0, -2) coordinate (K)
                -- ++(-2, 0, 0) coordinate (J)
                -- cycle;
        \coordinate (L) at (K -| H);
        \coordinate (I) at (J -| L);
        \draw (K)
                -- ++(0, -2, 0) coordinate (L)
                -- (H);
        \draw[dashed] (E) 
                -- ++(0, 0, -2) coordinate (I)
                -- (J);
        \draw[dashed] (E) -- (I) -- (L);
        
        \draw (F) -- (I) -- (H) -- cycle;
        \draw (J) -- (L) -- (G) -- cycle;
                
        \node[below left] at (E) {$000$};
        \node[diamond end] at (E) {};
        \node[above left] at (F) {$100$};
        \node[circle end] at (F) {};
        \node[right] at (G) {$110$};
        \node[triangle end] at (G) {};
        \node[below right] at (H) {$010$};
        \node[circle end] at (H) {};
        \node[above right] at (I) {$001$};
        \node[circle end] at (I) {};
        \node[above left] at (J) {$101$};
        \node[triangle end] at (J) {};
        \node[above right] at (K) {$111$};
        \node[diamond end] at (K) {};
        \node[right] at (L) {$011$};
        \node[triangle end] at (L) {};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer that you have to complete:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \node (00) at (0,0) {\large $\medblackdiamond$} node[below] at (00) {\Large $00$};
        \node (01) at (1,0) {\huge$\star$} node[below] at (01) {\Large $01$};
        \node (11) at (1,1) {\large$\medblackdiamond$} node[above] at (11) {\Large $11$};
        \node (10) at (0,1) {\huge$\star$} node[above] at (10) {\Large $10$};
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \node[above] (1) at (.5,0) {\Large $1$};
        \node[left] (2) at (0,.5) {\Large $1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]